# AWS cli is installed but doesn't work, Centos8

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, aws-cli, centos8

Hi I have installed awscli in centos8 trough pip3, I can see the files in my /root/.local/bin directory

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  817 Mar  4 18:50 aws
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  204 Mar  4 18:49 aws_bash_completer
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 1432 Mar  4 18:49 aws.cmd
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 1138 Mar  4 18:50 aws_completer
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 1807 Mar  4 18:49 aws_zsh_completer.sh
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  218 Mar  4 18:49 pyrsa-decrypt
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  234 Mar  4 18:49 pyrsa-decrypt-bigfile
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  218 Mar  4 18:49 pyrsa-encrypt
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  234 Mar  4 18:49 pyrsa-encrypt-bigfile
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  216 Mar  4 18:49 pyrsa-keygen
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  239 Mar  4 18:49 pyrsa-priv2pub
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  212 Mar  4 18:49 pyrsa-sign
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  216 Mar  4 18:49 pyrsa-verify
```

but when I try to entablish the credentials with "aws configure" or simply view the version with "aws --version" I get:

```
bash: aws: command not found
```

when I run "pip3 uninstall awscli" and before uninstalling it shows me a list of files, some of them I can not find when I look for them like the ones on the site-package folder, ex:

```
Uninstalling awscli-1.18.14:
  /root/.local/bin/aws
  /root/.local/bin/aws.cmd
  /root/.local/bin/aws_bash_completer
  /root/.local/bin/aws_completer
  /root/.local/bin/aws_zsh_completer.sh
  /root/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/awscli-1.18.14.dist-info/DESCRIPTION.rst
  /root/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/awscli-1.18.14.dist-info/INSTALLER
  /root/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/awscli-1.18.14.dist-info/METADATA
  /root/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/awscli-1.18.14.dist-info/RECORD
```

What should I do?

Comment: Is `/root/.local/bin` in your `$PATH`?

Comment: this is the output when I do and echo $PATH : /root/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin

Comment: So, it is not on your `PATH`, add it and try again, or run with full path

Comment: I was intalling awscli as root, exited root, instaled, and now it works, dont now why